# How to get three tables data in laravel7

Tags: laravel-7

i have three table country, state, customer_contacts.
I want display all customer details into list structure. But in my customer table only id save of country and state respectively.
Table structure as follows :

Country

```
id  name
1  India
2  Canada
```

State

```
id  name     country_id
1  Mumbai       1
2  Delhi        1
3  abc          2
4  xyz          2
```

Customer_contact

```
id  c_name     country_id  state_id
1   abcdee       1           2
2   xyzerr       1           1
3   extraa       2           3
4   newsss       2           4
```

i want to fetch customer name with country name and state name.

I am using below query to fetch data but getting only customer contact data how to fetch name uaing any query or relationship.

```
$data = CustomerContact::latest()->get();
```

If any solution then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You 2 have possibillities here:

First, you can use the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships):

CustomerContact model

```
country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

Country model

```
state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
```

Use the relationships like this:

```
$data = CustomerContact::with('country.state')->latest()->get();
```

Second option would be to use `join()`:

```
CustomerContact
    ::join('countries', 'countries.id', 'customer_contact.country_id')
    ->join('states', 'states.id', 'countries.state_id')
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

Comment: I am tried this one . when i do dd($data) in relationship i am getting null data.

Comment: I made the wrong relation, i should work like this now.